# fsck an active disk provides different results than fsck on an unmounted disk

Tags: linux, ext4, fsck

I have a VM running ubuntu LTS with an ext4 filesystem. We had performance problems that were related to IO tasks.
I checked the filesystem with

> fsck.ext4 -nv /dev/sda1
>   e2fsck 1.41.11 (14-Mar-2010)
>
> Warning!  /dev/sda1 is mounted.
>
> Warning: skipping journal recovery because doing a read-only
>   filesystem check.
>
> /dev/sda1 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
>
> Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
>
> Pass 2: Checking directory structure
>
> Entry 'pgstat.stat' in /var/lib/postgresql/8.4/main/pg_stat_tmp
>   (4721210) has deleted/unused inode 4732417.  Clear? no
>
> Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
>
> Pass 4: Checking reference counts
>
> Unattached zero-length inode 2127051.  Clear? no
>
> Unattached inode 2127051
>
> Connect to /lost+found? no
>
> Unattached inode 4757639
>
> Connect to /lost+found? no
>
> Pass 5: Checking group summary information
>
> Block bitmap differences:  -(1977109--1977118) -5190038 -7050074
>   -8435151 +8435477 -11906565 -(12532266--12532267) +13664464 +13664508 -13665161 +(13667660--13667674) -(13667675--13667729) -13669860 +(13671792--13671831) -(15571824--15571832) -(15582843--15582846) -16292177 -(16711922--16711928) -19144303 +19689076 -(22516788--22517441) -22635570 -(22974110--22974111) -(23736402--23736403) +(23956398--23957051) -24092764 -24832492
>
> Fix? no

while the machine was still running (-n), it reported a couples of failures, so we called the hoster of the VM to shut it down and do an fsck with the unmounted disk. 
The hoster said there are no FS errors reported by fsck, he attached an screenshot.

As the VM was up again, I repeated the fsck and got the same results.

Do the results differ because the filesystem is still mounted and is kind of "inconsistent"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is YES.  fsck assumes an unmounted, unchanging disk and that it has full control of the disk.

There are several passes that fsck uses, and these feed into each other, with the disk changing all the time, it is LIKELY that false errors are going to be registered.

I'm curious as to what information you feel you are getting by fsck'ing an active disk?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [free Hot Copy utility](http://r1soft.idera.com/tools/linux-hot-copy/) to snapshot and `fsck` a mounted filesystem to see if it really needs repair. You should **NOT** `fsck` an already mounted system in the manner you did.

```
hcp --skip-mount /dev/sda1
fsck -a -y /dev/hcp1
```

Please see: [Unable to list contents/remove directory (linux ext3)](https://serverfault.com/questions/441500/unable-to-list-contents-remove-directory-linux-ext3/441524#441524)

My guess is that you don't need repair at all. There are a world of issues that could result in poor I/O, though, spanning [kernel scheduling algorithms](https://serverfault.com/questions/430955/openfiler-iscsi-performance/431112#431112) to [failing disks](https://serverfault.com/questions/331499/how-can-a-single-disk-in-a-hardware-sata-raid-10-array-bring-the-entire-array-to/331504#331504) to lack of a quality RAID controller with [write cache](https://serverfault.com/questions/450242/what-is-the-memory-module-on-a-raid-card-needed-for/450253#450253).

Can you provide more information about your setup?

Comment: Thanks for the tool tip, the fsck did run with the -n flag on the mounted disk so no changes are made, turned out the performance problem was a problem with the storage of the hoster.